# Button Hiding the text in iOS6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a text box which has a popover. Also placed a button on top of the text box to make it clickable so that when button is clicked the popover is opened and any item selected will be shown in the text box. This is working fine in iOS7 but in iOS 6 i am able to select the item in popover but the button is hiding the text. Tried setting colour of button but didn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Set UIButtonTypeCustom for iOS 6

Comment: pradhyuman Chavda .thanks ..it worked.. but whats the diff between system and custom..initially it i had system..

Comment: can i write my comment as a answer? Will you accept it?

Comment: For more details about UIButton please check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the type of the button to "Custom", and you don't set an Image or a Background Image, the button will be invisible on versions prior to iOS7 too.

If you create the button programmatically:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

If you change it on your interface:

[image: Change Button Type]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using button, you can open popover by `UITextbox` itself. Just place the button's `IBAction` code in textbox's `IBAction` with `EditDidBegin` Event.

Answer (score 0):

Set UIbutton's buttontyoe to UIButtonTypeCustom for iOS 6